# Get value of paragraphs with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

so basically I have around 20 paragraphs that are inside a slider, and with every paragraph there's a share button that copies it's innerHTML.

Example:

```
<p class="parag">content</p>
<button onclick="share();"></button>
<p class="parag">diff content</p>
<button onclick="share();"></button>
<p class="parag">another content</p>
<button onclick="share();"></button>
```

Can I make something like an array in order to get one paragraph at a time? Because when I press the first share button the code copies the first paragraph and if I press the second share button I still have the first paragraph being copied and not the second one.
Hope I explained my issue right and thank you in advance.

Comment: i think you should include the function for `share();`

Comment: I did, I made a typo while writing the example code :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('button').click(function(e) {
     alert($(this).prev(".parag").text());
   });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="parag">content</p>
<button onclick="share();">content</button>
<p class="parag">diff content</p>
<button onclick="share();">diff</button>
<p class="parag">another content</p>
<button onclick="share();">another</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    myArray = [];
    $("p").each(function(){ 
         alert($(this).attr("class")) 
         myArray.push($(this).attr("class"))
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="parag">content</p>
<button onclick="share();"></button>
<p class="parag">diff content</p>
<button onclick="share();"></button>
<p class="parag">another content</p>
<button onclick="share();"></button>
```

Comment: Nope did not work. What I tried to do was getting the class.value  and then inside the share function I added test[1] (test is the var that I assigned)

Comment: ok i have add for p class and array acces everywhere in your javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
function share(element) {
    $(element).prev('p').text();    //the p tag content based on the button
}
```

also mention `this` in the funtion

`<button onclick="share(this);"></button>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$('button').click(function(e) {
  alert($(this).prev().text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="parag">content</p>
<button>Share</button>
<p class="parag">diff content</p>
<button>Share</button>
<p class="parag">another content</p>
<button>Share</button>
```

Pure **JS**:

```js
function share(ele) {
  alert(ele.previousElementSibling.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<p class="parag">content</p>
<button onclick="share(this);">Share</button>
<p class="parag">diff content</p>
<button onclick="share(this);">Share</button>
<p class="parag">another content</p>
<button onclick="share(this);">Share</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

***HTML***:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="parag">content</p>
<button>1</button>
<p class="parag">diff content</p>
<button>2</button>
<p class="parag">another content</p>
```

---

***Javascript***

```
function share(button) {
    alert(button.prev().text());
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        share($(this))
     });
});
```

<kbd>[**JS Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj8au5hv/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

`<p class="parag">content</p>
<button onclick="share(this);"></button>
<p class="parag">diff content</p><button onclick="share(this);"></button>
<p class="parag">another content</p><button onclick="share(this);"></button>`

share function

```
function share(that){ alert($(that).prev('.parag').html()); }
```